# Products do not show on home page today

Tags: products

Today when I looked at my site all the products are gone from the home page.  When I check the catalog the products are still in the database and none of the values have changed.  If I search, I find the product or if I look at the category the product is there, just not on the home page.  Thoughts??

Comment: what collection of product are you showing at home?

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some digging around, I figured out the catalog needed to be reindexed.  It was green and looked fine on the index page.  After I reindexed everything reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of products are you showing in your homepage? If they're new products, check if this attribute Set Product as New to Date has a valid date